# Can anyone help me make this code more efficient, make it faster

Tags: java, performance

I have made this code really badly. Can anyone tell me how to make this code better, smaller and more efficient. I know there is a better way to do this but cannot figure out how to.

```
public static String finalResult(String result[])
{
    String final_result = "";

    if (result[0].contains("NO ANSWERS"))
        final_result += "-";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[0]) < 50 & Integer.parseInt(result[0]) >= 0)
        final_result += "E";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[0]) > 50)
        final_result += "I";

    else
        final_result += "X";

    if (result[1].contains("NO ANSWERS"))
        final_result += "-";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[1]) < 50 && Integer.parseInt(result[1]) >= 0)
        final_result += "S";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[1]) > 50)
        final_result += "N";

    else
        final_result += "X";

    if (result[2].contains("NO ANSWERS"))
        final_result += "-";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[2]) < 50 && Integer.parseInt(result[2]) >= 0)
        final_result += "T";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[2]) > 50)
        final_result += "F";

    else
        final_result += "X";

    if (result[3].contains("NO ANSWERS"))
        final_result += "-";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[3]) < 50 && Integer.parseInt(result[3]) >= 0)
        final_result += "J";

    else if (Integer.parseInt(result[3]) > 50)
        final_result += "P";

    else
        final_result += "X";

    return final_result;
}
```

I need it to take the least possible amount of time. I am a 7th grader trying to finish my cs assignment. It needs to be the best it can be. Please help me.

Comment: You could start making it more maintainable by adding curly braces to all the branches...

Comment: Then refactor to a method accepting a result, and the desired return value corresponding to 0-49, 50+.

Comment: I was considering migrating this to [CodeReview.SE], but it is currently not in a state where it would be on-topic there, either. You need a clear problem statement: what does the code do? how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static String finalResult(String result[]) {
        StringBuilder final_result = new StringBuilder();
        String[] betweenZeroAnd50 = new String[] { "E", "S", "T", "J" }; 
        String[] greatherThan50 = new String[] { "I", "N", "F", "P" };
        if (result.length == 4) {
            //instead of writing 3 times if with same condition and only index changes so avoid repeatly code and use loop.
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (result[i].contains("NO ANSWERS")) {
                    final_result.append("-");
                } else if (isNumeric(result[i]) && Integer.parseInt(result[i]) >= 0
                        && Integer.parseInt(result[0]) < 50) {
                    final_result.append(betweenZeroAnd50[i]);
                } else if (isNumeric(result[i]) && Integer.parseInt(result[i]) > 50) {
                    final_result.append(greatherThan50[i]);
                } else {
                    final_result.append("X");
                }
            }
        }
        return final_result.toString();
    }

 public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TheCoder add custom `isNumeric` Method or you can add an external library use it here a link for adding external library http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44 and library is http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: yes see i updated answer, removed `stringUtils` and created one method `isNumeric`

Comment: make sure your result[] array has 3 only length.

Comment: You forgot the last j/p value, So it works now and it has taken about 70% percent less time, I am truly very thankful